# decide wich interface to implement base on system configuration magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a **dropdown** to select which data source to use (`system.xml`) and I got the value **selected** using a plugin after clicking to button **'save configuration'**.

Now I need to specific which interface to implement based on that param .

> exp : if I choose 'mysql' as a data source . My class will implement
>   interface which contains Methods related to this data source .

Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: to me it's unclear what you are asking. please try to rephrase your question. also please show us what you tried.